# IPTables from public ip and port to lan ip

Tags: debian, iptables, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I own 3 public IPs for my server and I have multiple VMs that have their own 'job'.
The server has 1 NIC.
Public IPs:

- XX.XX.9.247 (MAIN)
- XX.XX.21.141 (additional)
- XX.XX.21.142 (additional)

LAN IPs:

- 10.10.0.0/24
- 10.10.0.10:80 (Webserver for the MAIN IP)
- 10.10.0.20:80 (Webserver for the 1. add. IP)
- 10.10.0.30:80 (Webserver for the 2. add. IP)
- 10.10.0.31:9987 (TeamSpeak for the 2. add. IP)

and so on and so forth.

Example:
Request comes from XX.XX.21.141:80. The request gets send to 10.10.0.20:80. The vserver sends the packet back via XX.XX.21.141.

Why I do it like that? Because I want to rent some vservers out.

I know how to achieve that with IPTables on one public IP but have no idea how to do that with multiple public IPs.

I hope you guys can help me.

Greetings

Comment: Can you tell exactly what are you trying clearly? i am just guessing you are trying to "assign" each of your wan ips to a local/virtual machine right?

Comment: I want that if someone who tries to connect to my server via the wan ip "xx.xx.21.141" is connecting to one of the virtual machines with local ip with port forwarding. For example

"xx.xx.21.141:80 -> 10.10.0.20:80" and "xx.xx.21.141:8000 -> 10.10.0.21:8000"

Comment: all the ports of wan ip or just specific ports ?

Comment: I want specific ports from a specific IP to send packets to a specific private IP.

Comment: then you need iptables to forward packets / NAT. 
Which virtualisation tech you are using? consider that your Host machine may interfere traffic to VMs.

Comment: I'm using Proxmox as hypervisor (KVM)

Answer (score 0):

If you want redirect only http/https it's better user nginx (but you can apache)
Depending on what your Web Server is (Apache, NGinx) you should consider an HTTP Proxy on your front-end server:

- [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) (NGinx)
- [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_proxy.html) (Apache)

You can use bridges to provide for some VM dedicated IPs.

Iptables solution

```
                                 iptables
                                     |                   .---------------.
    .-,(  ),-.                       v               port 80             |
 .-(          )-.        port 80  ________               |               |
(    internet    )------------>[_...__...°]------------->|      VM       |
 '-(          ).-'    XX.XX.9.247    ^   10.10.0.10      |               |
     '-.( ).-'                       |                   |               |
                                     |                   '---------------'
                                     |
                                     |
                                   __  _ 
                                  [__]|=|
                                  /::/|_|
```

This is script

```
#!/bin/sh
# eth1 is WAN
WAN=eth1
MAIN_IP=XX.XX.9.247
MAIN_PORT=80
BACK_END_IP=10.10.0.10
BACK_END_PORT=80

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# it's clean all tables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ${WAN} -d ${MAIN_IP} --dport ${MAIN_PORT} -j DNAT --to-destination ${BACK_END_IP}:${BACK_END_PORT}
iptables -A FORWARD -d ${MAIN_IP} --dport ${MAIN_PORT} -j ACCEPT
#maybe this# iptables -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: That would be a great solution for the http-requests. But I don't only have http-requests. I would now try to create a bridge for each IP I have and try to do some iptables-stuff.